# Writing quotechar to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I use the `csv.writer()` to write some values to my file.
My delimiter is `";"`.

Now I want that the value `pnr` hast quotechars in the file - like:

```
1;12;2014;"110585";200;20.10.2014;;28.10.2014;N;;;
1;12;2014;"110603";200;06.10.2014;;07.10.2014;N;;;
```

I tried this:

```
pnr = '\"' + str(pnr) + '\"'
```

and got this traceback:

```
writer.writerow(l)
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

I know what it means but i do not have any solutions.

Comment: note: avoid `+` operator with strings e.g. do `'\"' + str(pnr) + '\"'` as `'"%s"' % pnr`. Btw, read this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372673/1673391 if it answers you.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Or like the docs says '{}'.format(pnr)